# sending html form radio box results by email?

Tags: php, html

can someone please help i am trying to email the results of 4 radio boxes from my form by email. i receive the email fine but am not getting the results sent through.

can someone show me what im doing wrong?

html form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Site Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="send_feedback.php" method="POST">
<div  class="wrapper_feedback" align="left">
  <p>Website Design:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="design" value="design1"> 
    1
    <input type="radio" name="design" value="design2"> 
    2
    <input type="radio" name="design" value="design3" checked> 
    3
     <input type="radio" name="design" value="design4"> 
    4
     <input type="radio" name="design" value="design5"> 
    5
  </p>
  <hr>
<p>Ease of Use:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="easeuse" value="ease1"> 
    1
    <input type="radio" name="easeuse" value="ease2"> 
    2
    <input type="radio" name="easeuse" value="ease3" checked> 
    3
     <input type="radio" name="easeuse" value="ease4"> 
    4
     <input type="radio" name="easeuse" value="ease5"> 
    5
  </p>
    <hr>
<p>Fit for Purpose:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="purpose1"> 
    1
    <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="purpose2"> 
    2
    <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="purpose3" checked>
    3     
    <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="purpose4"> 
    4
     <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="purpose5"> 
    5
  </p>
      <hr>
<p>Layout:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="layout" value="layout1"> 
    1
    <input type="radio" name="layout" value="layout2"> 
    2
    <input type="radio" name="layout" value="layout3" checked>
    3     
    <input type="radio" name="layout" value="layout4"> 
    4
     <input type="radio" name="layout" value="layout5"> 
    5
   </p>
   <input type="submit" action="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
  <br>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "info@mydomain.com";

$subject = "site Feedback";

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "somesite.com Feedback

$design
$easeuse
$purpose
$layout

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
$_SESSION['feedback']="<div class=\"infobox-index\"><strong>Thank You</strong> - We appreciate you taking the time to tell us what you think.</div>"; 
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
exit();
?>
<?php ob_end_flush() ?>
```

Comment: rather than $design should you be referring to it as $_POST['design'] to get the variable from the POST?

Comment: Is this your entire script? I feel that the variables in the string will have no value if the script doesn't pull them. Also, try logging the values somewhere before you send the mail so you can see if you are at least getting correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is relying on [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) which is deprecated and discouraged. You should access the data with:

```
$_POST['design']
```

Not:

```
$design
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these variables:

```
$design
$easeuse
$purpose
$layout
```

use this:

```
$_POST['design']
$_POST['easeuse']
$_POST['purpose']
$_POST['layout']
```

Comment: if i use them i get this error? 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ptb1/send_feedback.php on line 11

Comment: Try putting the code on one line as your white space is irrelevant anyway. And make sure you're not using the wrong quote style.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the POST variables sent from the form using the following syntax:

```
$_POST['design']
$_POST['easeuse']
$_POST['purpose']
$_POST['layout']
```